# How can tune the plot colors, labels, etc. to make it beautiful?

Tags: r, colors

What's the meaning of beautiful chart for humans and which theme or color gradients should use, so everybody could say, visually beautiful color and harmony used for the specific chart. Especially, I want to tune colors, labels, etc. in R histogram to gain full mark in my homework. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you define beauty?

Comment: Actually, I have this question too, so I edit my question. @EliKorvigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to have a beautiful histogram

`col <- c("#B2182B", "#D6604D", "#F4A582" ,"#FDDBC7", "#D1E5F0", "#92C5DE", "#4393C3" ,"#2166AC")`

`hist(precip,breaks = 13,col=cm.colors(5),freq =F,xlab = "xlab",ylab = "ylab",main = "main")`
your output be something like this : 
[image]

or this one to have more colorful plot
`hist(precip,breaks = 13,col=rainbow(13),freq =F,xlab = "xlab",ylab = "ylab",main = "main")`
your output be something like this : 
[image]

for more details about the attribute of hist function you can look at this link:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.3/topics/hist